# knockout.js: $index and $data together in one text binding

Tags: knockout.js

I'd like to join `$index` and `$data` in text binding:

```html
<ul data-bind='foreach: myItems'>
    <li data-bind="text: $index() + ': ' + $data()"></li>
</ul>
```

but the syntax above is not working. Is such scenario not supported in KO? Have I to write some helper function or computed observable into my model?

Comment: What is the error you are getting then?

Comment: What is your `$data`? Maybe try with: `<li data-bind="text: $index() + ': ' + $data"></li>`

Comment: @PaulManzotti: TypeError: $data is not a function;

Comment: I'd try @nemesv's suggestion then. If not that, then debug, and see what $data is.

Comment: $data isn't an observable then?

Comment: myItems is ko.observableArray()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have functions inside the `myItems` array your `$data` won't be normally a function so you don't need the `()`:

As your exception also tells this:

> TypeError: $data is not a function;

So the following code should work:

```html
<ul data-bind='foreach: myItems'>
    <li data-bind="text: $index() + ': ' + $data"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Even if you have observables in the array, `$data` won't be observable. But don't try that since it there's a [bug in Knockout](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/issues/482) regarding that.